# JSON object not unmarshalling, but not throwing errors

Tags: go

I'm just trying to do some basic JSON unmarshalling for this item:

```
testJson := `{
        "Users": [
          {
                "id": 1,
                "username": "bbrewer"
          },
          {
                "id": 2,
                "username": "rsmith"
          },
          {
                "id": 3,
                "username": "jmorgan"
          },
          {
                "id": 4,
                "username": "dwallis"
          }]
        }`
```

I'm trying to do it in such a way that I can work with the individual components for each entry (so like user.ID or user.UserName). I've set up a struct for it like this:

```
type UserInfo struct {
        ID              int     `json:"id"`
        UserName        string  `json:"username"`
}
```

However, whenever I try to unmarshal it, while it doesn't throw any errors, it doesn't seem to be parsing it properly. When I try to print using a range, nothing is outputted, and it seems like the object I'm trying to tie it to is just empty. What am I doing wrong?
Here's my full code (note that I've also tried it without the UserList type, with users as the UserInfo struct type):

```
package main

import "fmt"
//import "net/http"
//import "io/ioutil"
import "encoding/json"

type UntypedJson map[string][]interface{}

type UserInfo struct {
        ID              int     `json:"id"`
        UserName        string  `json:"username"`
}

type UserList []UserInfo

func main() {
        testJson := `{
        "Users": [
          {
                "id": 1,
                "username": "bbrewer"
          },
          {
                "id": 2,
                "username": "rsmith"
          },
          {
                "id": 3,
                "username": "jmorgan"
          },
          {
                "id": 4,
                "username": "dwallis"
          }]
        }`

        var users UserList
        json.Unmarshal([]byte(testJson), &users)
        for i, v := range users {
                fmt.Println("what do")
                fmt.Println(i)
                fmt.Println(v)
                fmt.Println(v.ID)
                fmt.Println(v.UserName)
        }
}
```

Comment: You say it's not providing any errors, but you're completely ignoring errors. Don't do that. It actually _is_ producing an error, which you can see here: https://play.golang.org/p/ZFXecIWEDOQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code obviously getting an error and you haven't handled it. first handle error like below.

```
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(testJson), &users)
    if err != nil {
        //handle error here.
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
```

Answer to your question, you have to create a type including `UserInfo` array as below. Because your json string has annotated as `"Users":[{}]`

```
type UsersInfo struct {
    Users []UserInfo `json:"Users"`
}
```

And unmarshal your json to the `UsersInfo` type variable reference.

```
    var users UsersInfo
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(testJson), &users)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
```

You can run full code [here](https://play.golang.org/p/bQjZRWCHNM6).

Comment: You are 100% right. I'm running my binary in the command line and it wasn't throwing the error there. Thank you so much!!

Comment: @res12345 It doesn't "throw" an error there because you are explicitly ignoring the error.